# How to redirect oldblog.com/any-post.html to newblog.com/any-post.html in blogger

Tags: web, blogs

I have set custom domain on my blogger account bow I need to change my blog domain again without losing seo. How can I redirect my oldblog.com/any-post.html to newblog.com/any-post.html. I can redirect my oldblog.com to newblog.com but can't redirect post URLs like oldblog.com/any-post.html to newblog.com/any-post.html. please help I stuck here

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do it, you need to contact with your domain providers. Ask them to update your DNS settings. You need to update following I.ps in the A-section:

```
216.239.32.21
216.239.34.21
216.239.36.21
216.239.38.21
```

Also other changes should be made which you have in that file which was downloaded when you were connecting your domain to your blog.

The conclusion is you need to make changes in DNS of your domain and set it to redirect your old domain URLS to new domain URLs.

Here is a post which may help you. https://support.google.com/blogger/answer/1233387?visit_id=1-636264533431348716-1244965263&p=customdomain&hl=en&rd=2